# how to show up value from syntax?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to show up value, from 3 condition;  I want to display the results of the formula if it's lacking in numbers, however, if it's more then it doesn't display the results; if "=" display "Ballance".

example:

```
cell  ||   L     ||   K
   21 ||  12     ||   2 
   22 ||  12     ||   22
=IF(L22=K22;"Ballance ";IF(L22-K22;"True";IF(L22>K22"False")))
```

how must i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
=IF(L22=K22;"Ballance";IF(L22<K22;L22-K22;""))
```

EDIT: Updated to fit OP's requirements (see comments)

Comment: sorry I mean, I want to display the results of the formula if it's lacking in numbers, however, if it's more then it doesn't display the results

Comment: So what are the desired outputs for each of the 3 cases: 1. L22 = K22, 2. L22 < K22, 3. L22 > K22?

Comment: yes I want to display output in these 3 conditions, so if the value is the same he will produce "Ballance", if it is less then he will produce a value or number, if more then it does not display the value (false)

Comment: So if it is less, what value or number do you want as the output?

Comment: yes like that, if he is lacking then he will produce a number; example (12 <22 = -10) so the result obtained is "-10". if he is more then I will temporarily hide the results or he is wrong than I want to find (because I only want to bring up values ​​that are less than) or "  ". but if he has the same value it will bring up the status "Ballance"

Comment: I updated the code, now if it's equal it will output "Ballance", if L22 is less, it will output L22-K22 (e.g. "-10"), if L22 is greater than K22 the cell will be empty

Comment: Please consider marking the question as answered (checkmark to the left of the answer) if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(L22=K22,"Ballance ",IF(L22<K22,"",IF(L22>K22,"")))
```

This formula will produce the results as follows

1. L22 cell value is equal to the cell value of K22 then  "Ballance "
2. L22 cell value is less than the cell value of K22 then it will show as blank
3. L22 cell value is greater than the cell value of K22 then it will show as blank

Comment: You can leave out one of the `IF` formulas like this: `=IF(L22=K22;"Balance";IF(L22<K22;"True";"False"))`

Comment: ya, if it is false then the result "   " or I do not want to bring it up, because in this statement I only want to display the "ballance" status and numbers, if he is less than the initial column or L22. like that